# Custom Android map location App

Tags: android, maps

Hey Guys, I am making an android app that will display nearest shopping mall to the user.

I want to know that how do i develop app that can open google map in which i have marked the places.

For example if a person is going from place A to B. I want to display all the shopping mall as he moves from A to B. But in the public google maps it will shop up everything that will come up from place A to B like hospitals, schools etc. I just want that only shopping malls should be shown.

How to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following example to draw pin/overlay on Google map:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Check following api to fetch nearest location:

https://simplegeo.com/docs/api-endpoints/simplegeo-places

With combination of above two you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Could you please explain it little bit or suggest me a open app with source so i can take help